How to force a specific entry to be last in natbib?
I'm writing a document in latex using natbib for bibliography management. My problem is that I need one specific entry last in the bibliography, with other references being ordered by citations. I use the bibliography style gost2008, which sorts references by citation order. Is it possible to force one specific entry(this entry is not cited last) to be later in the typeset bibliography?

Welcome to TeX.SE. "The bibliography style I  use sorts references by citation order" -- Are you at liberty to divulge this secret?

I'm afraid your write-up is a bit confusing. The statement 'I need one specific entry to be last in the bibliography" isn't clear. E.g., does the entry have to be last in the bib file, or does it have to last in the formatted/typeset bibliography?

@Mico I'm using gost2008.

@Mico The entry has to be last in the typeset bibliography.

At least on my system (TL2024) the gost2008.bst has a fatal error. Since the bibliography is in citation order, just add \nocite{LastEntry} at the end of your document (after any other citations) and it will appear last.
